# Как правильно вывести в json данные с QTableView?

Tags: c++, json, qt

Есть цикл по проходу по всей таблице:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_model->rowCount(); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m_model->columnCount(); ++j) {
       //Вывод данных в переменную
    }
}
```

Так вот какой тип данных надо чтобы правильно вывести информацию из таблицы в json файл. И как правильно записывать в json. С загрузкой из json в таблицу я разобрался а вот сохранение. Можете помочь ?

Comment: вероятно, строка

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта.

1. Вручную сформировать строку

   ```
   QString s="[";
   for (int i = 0; i < m_model->rowCount(); ++i) {
       if (i==0) s+="[";else s+=",[";
       for (int j = 0; j < m_model->columnCount(); ++j) {
           if (j!=0) s+=",";
           s+="\""+m_model->item (i, j)->text()+"\"";
           //Вывод данных в переменную
       }
       s+="]";
   }
   s+="]";
   ```
2. Использовать классы для json

   ```
   QJsonArray tab;
   for (int i = 0; i < m_model->rowCount(); ++i) {
       QJsonArray row;
       if (i==0) s+="[";else s+=",[";
       for (int j = 0; j < m_model->columnCount(); ++j) {
           row.append(m_model->item (i, j)->text());
       }
       tab.append(row);
   }
   s+="]";
   QJsonDocument doc;
   doc.setObject (tab);
   QString s = QString (doc.toJson());
   ```